# BrowserSync - proxying with wrong encoding

Tags: javascript, browser-sync

I want to use browser sync to proxy my remote website. My gulp task is as follows:

```
gulp.task('proxy', function() {
  var bs = require('browser-sync');
  var browserSync = bs.create();
  var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

  browserSync.init({
    browser: [],
    proxy: {
      target: proxyUrl,
      proxyReq: [
        function(proxyReq) {
          proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=windows-1250');
        }
      ],
      proxyRes: [
        function(proxyRes, req, res) {
          console.log(proxyRes.headers);
        }
      ]
    },
    // rewriteRules: [
    //   { // enable if you want to use unminified versions of files
    //     match: /\.min/g,
    //     replace: ''
    //   }
    // ],
    serveStatic: ['.', './public/']
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the site in encoded in `windows 1250` and displays wrong. What can I do?